# Unable to save Android user input in SQl datable

Tags: android, sql

I am new to android and trying to build a todo list android app that uses SQL database to save Edittext userinput,the database has 1 table and 4 column (date,Description,title,time) but when i try to save it with an onClick event it give the following error.

```
08-07 00:05:52.015 11463-11463/com.naive.LISTY E/SQLiteLog: (1) table tasks has no column named date
08-07 00:05:52.026 11463-11463/com.naive.LISTY E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting date=12/12/12 Description=hello world title=hello time=12:30
                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tasks has no column named date (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tasks(date,Description,title,time) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                     at listy.naive.com.listy.Dialog$override.Add_task(Dialog.java:64)
                                                                     at listy.naive.com.listy.Dialog$override.access$dispatch(Dialog.java)
                                                                     at listy.naive.com.listy.Dialog.Add_task(Dialog.java:0)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

SQLcontact code

```
public class TaskContract {
public static final String DB_NAME = "com.aziflaj.todolist.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE = "tasks";
    public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COL_TASK_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String COL_TASK_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COL_TASK_TIME = "time";
}}
```

SQLdbHelper (TaskDbHelper)

```
public TaskDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE + "TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME + "TEXT NOT NULL; )";

    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}}
```

Activity(Dialog.java) code

```
public class Dialog extends AppCompatActivity {

private TaskDbHelper mHelper;
private ListView mTaskListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
    mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(this);

}



public void Cancel(View view) {

    finish();
}

public void Add_task(View view) {

    EditText mTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_field);
    String Title = String.valueOf(mTitle.getText());

     EditText mTask = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description_field);
     String Task = String.valueOf(mTask.getText());

    EditText mDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_field);
    String Date = String.valueOf(mDate.getText());

    EditText mTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_field);
    String Time = String.valueOf(mTime.getText());

    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, Title);
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DESCRIPTION, Task);
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE, Date);
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME, Time);

    db.insert(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();


}
```

when deleted the **values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE, Date);** it started giving error for column time and respectively for other.

Comment: During your testing did you ever create the database without the table, or the table without those columns?  If so you need to either delete it, or raise the version # so your onUpgrade is called.

Comment: Trying your solution

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.naive.LISTY, PID: 29927
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.naive.LISTY/listy.naive.com.listy.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ";": syntax error (code)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this

```
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE
        + " ( " +
        TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT NOT NULL," +
        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME + "TEXT NOT NULL; )";
```

please check spaces for "TEXT NOT NULL," you should include spaces... it should be like " TEXT NOT NULL," For TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DESCRIPTION and also for TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME.. and remove semicolon after NOT NULL; in the end
and uninstall and reinstall the app on your test device.

Comment: did you uninstall app and reinstall?? coz the previous table will still be there if u havent uninstalled app on your test device..